# 2 HTML Selects with 1 Input Submit Button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html-select

I tried to search several topics but couldn't find any best answer suiting my needs.

I want to create 2 select forms with URL as the option values and just 1 submit button. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve are :-

1. If select form 1 & select form 2 contains no selected value, the Submit button will do nothing.
2. If select form 1 contain any selected value, select form 2 will reset to default value.
3. If select form 2 contain any selected value, select form 1 will reset to default value.
4. Clicking the Submit button will go to the value URL of either select form 1 or select form 2.

This is what I've achieve so far.

```js
function go(){
location=
document.form.example.
options[document.form.example.selectedIndex].value
}


$('#service-select').change(function(){
  $('#contact-select').val( $('#contact-select').prop('defaultSelected') );
});

$('#contact-select').change(function(){
  $('#service-select').val( $('#service-select').prop('defaultSelected') );
});

$('#mySubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');

$('#service-select, #contact-select').change(function() {
    if($(this).val()!==""){
        $('#mySubmit').removeAttr('disabled');

    }
else {
$('#mySubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
<select name="example" id="service-select">
<option value="">Select Service</option>
<option class="select-field" value="https://service1.com">Service 1</option>
<option class="select-field" value="https://service2.com">Service 2</option>
<option class="select-field" value="https://service3.com">Service 3</option>
</select>
</form>

<form name="form">
<select name="example" id="contact-select">
<option value="">Select Contact</option>
<option class="select-field" value="https://contact1.com">Contact 1</option>
<option class="select-field" value="https://contact2.com">Contact 2</option>
<option class="select-field" value="https://contact3.com">Contact 3</option>
</select>
</form>

<input id="mySubmit" type="button" name="test" value="GO" onClick="go()">
```

All seems working fine except when I pick one of the select option, and I click the submit button, nothing happen and in console there's this error saying "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined**" . But if I delete one of the Select form, the submit button is working.

May I know why and how to fix it? And forgive my JavaScript/jQuery codes, as I mix & match it from several resources to achieve what I got so far.

Comment: You have two forms with `name="form"` and two selects with `name="example"` so `document.form.example...` is hard to JS determine which one you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find select whose selected value is not first option so you can either loop through selects and get the select value whose value is not `""` or use `:selected:not(:contains('Select'))` to get value of select which doesn't contains `Select..` as selected value.

***Demo code*** :

```js
function go() {
  var locations;
  //loop through form > select
  $("form select").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      locations = $(this).val() //add value in variable
    }
  })
  //find select which doesn't contains `select` as slected options
  var other_way = $("form select option:selected:not(:contains('Select'))").val()

  console.log(other_way)
  console.log(locations)
  //redirect from here..
}


$('#service-select').change(function() {
  $('#contact-select').val($('#contact-select').prop('defaultSelected'));
});

$('#contact-select').change(function() {
  $('#service-select').val($('#service-select').prop('defaultSelected'));
});

$('#mySubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#service-select, #contact-select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() !== "") {
    $('#mySubmit').removeAttr('disabled');

  } else {
    $('#mySubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
  <select name="example" id="service-select">
    <option value="">Select Service</option>
    <option class="select-field" value="https://service1.com">Service 1</option>
    <option class="select-field" value="https://service2.com">Service 2</option>
    <option class="select-field" value="https://service3.com">Service 3</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form name="form">
  <select name="example" id="contact-select">
    <option value="">Select Contact</option>
    <option class="select-field" value="https://contact1.com">Contact 1</option>
    <option class="select-field" value="https://contact2.com">Contact 2</option>
    <option class="select-field" value="https://contact3.com">Contact 3</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input id="mySubmit" type="button" name="test" value="GO" onClick="go()">
```